# Why doesn't Stack, Queue and List shrink the internal array after removing an item?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, data-structures, collections

In .NET, `Stack`, `Queue` and `List` (as well as their generic implementations) use an array internally to hold the items.

When adding new element, the size of the internal array doubles on `Push()`, `Enqueue()` or `Add()` if it is full.

The question is, why doesn't these data structures *halve* an internal array when item is being *removed*? It would be a good idea to halve the size of the array on `Pop()`, `Dequeue()` or `Remove()` if it is less than one-quarter full to prevent the waste of memory.

I used the following code to check this behavior:

```
var s = new Stack<int>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 512; i++) s.Push(i); // Increases the array capacity to 1024.
for (int i = 0; i <= 512; i++) s.Pop();   // Doesn't decrease array capacity.

// Stack is empty, but internal array capacity is still 1024:
var fieldInfo = typeof(Stack<int>).GetField("_array", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
Console.WriteLine((fieldInfo.GetValue(s) as int[]).Length);
```

Comment: Interesting post and I hope it gets answered. I would assume the reason why is because that allocating memory to double an array is expensive and someone who is repeatedly hovering around the border of the full array would find their add operations v. expensive. i.e, say my stack is 500 elements in size. I push another 1, so it doubles to 1000. Then I remove one and it drops to 500 (in your example). I'd then have to allocate 500 more spaces to add another element.

Comment: Actually, it will not drop back to 500 after popping 501th item, because the suggestion was to resize internal array when it's less than one-quarter full. So It will halve to 500 when there'll be 250 items in the stack.

Comment: Alright, I get you. In which case I think fragmentation would come into play here. And also it would wreck locality

Comment: Just use `TrimExcess` if you need the internal arrays to shrink.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely efficiency.

Shrinking and growing an array involves copying the array around in memory; you can't simply tag a small amount of new memory onto an existing allocation and subsequently remove it from an allocation: allocations are of a fixed size in the operating system, so if you want to increase the size of an array, you actually have to allocate a new block of memory, copy all the contents over from the source to the destination, and then delete the old allocation. It's a similar operation for shrinking as well. This can be time consuming.

Now given that an array has already grown to a given size, it's a good indicator for .NET (or any other framework) for the optimal size of that array. Even if items are removed from it, there's a chance that the array could grow to the same size again: .NET isn't Mystic Meg so won't know that you're never going to use blocks of that array again. So rather than constantly allocate and deallocate blocks of memory, it's more efficient to grow the allocation until it doesn't need to grow again, and then only worry about cleaning it up when the variable is goes out of scope and becomes a target for the GC.

Comment: With that being said, wouldn't it make sense to introduce `GreedyList`, `GreedyStack` and `GreedyQueue` classes to the framework for scenarios where a small memory footprint is more important than execution time?

Comment: If you want a small memory footprint, you wouldn't use something like .NET or Java where you have very little control over memory :-) That might sound arrogant, but it's a case of using the right tool for the job. That said, writing the code for an array that "releases" memory (for a given value of "release" as you're reliant on the garbage collector) when items are removed shouldn't be that hard if you really need it.

Comment: @StevenLiekens `List(T)` and I assume the others as well aren't sealed so you could fairly easily extend the class with the methods you suggested...just have the remove function remove the item and then move the remaining items to a new `List(T)` and return the reference.

Comment: @ChrisJ Not sure that I'd agree that .NET/Java are bad for this situation as (from what I remember) the GC takes available resources into consideration.  Once there is no longer a reference to the "over-sized" `List`/`Array` it will be up for GC whenever those resources are needed.

Comment: You're still reliant on the GC though: even if the GC releases memory in the managed heap, there's no guarantee that the memory will be released back to the operating system, or if it is it won't necessarialy release all of it: some memory will still be reserved by .NET for the managed heap (so allocated by the operating system to .NET, but otherwise unused by the .NET app) otherwise .NET itself ends up being bad with memory resouces. The question becomes /why/ does memory matter? There may be ways to reuse objects rather than creating/destroying them, that might help the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Because *often*, when you shrink a list, it is only temporary, and you intend to allow it to grow again later. So removing the memory would incur a double cost: first, you have to release the current array and allocate a new, smaller one (and copy the contents to the new array). And then later on, you would have to release *that* again to allocate a bigger one (and then copy all the elements again).

At the same time, if you know that you want to *permanently* shrink a list, and the amount of memory saved is worth it, then you have a method for doing that: just allocate a new list and copy the relevant entries to that. So when you *do* want to shrink the list, you have a way to do that. But at the same time, the *default* behavior tries to avoid needless copies of data. There's generally no reason to copy data to a smaller array.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two reasons.

1. As the items gets added to the `List` or `Stack` etc the `Capacity` property grows, don't forget that capacity property can be set explicitly by user. What if user sets the explicitly? Framework shouldn't overrule it isn't it? There needs to maintain more state in order to implement this feature to identify whether user set the capacity or `List` itself adjusted. It will add unnecessary complexity.
2. Efficiency. Assume you remove an element at that stage runtime decides to reduce the array size, what if you add elements immediately? Size will grow by `Size * 2` that's how it is implemented. What if you keep on adding and removing at hot spots which does the reallocation? Allocating memory often can hurt performance and adds garbage, which puts load into GC.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this behavior reflects the intended usage of these classes. Especially the `Queue` and the `Stack` are intended as short-lived mechanisms to facilitate calculations occurring in a single thread. They are not intended as buffers between threads. On the contrary the [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1) ([source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentQueue.cs.html)) is implemented more efficiently as a linked-list of small arrays, but is intended as buffer for multithreaded producer-consumer scenarios. A `ConcurrentQueue` may live for a long time, and could be almost empty most of the time. It makes sense to not retain the maximum size it obtained during a burst of incoming data.

---

**Update:** Here is a basic implementation of a `Queue` that grows and shrinks automatically. Internally it is a `LinkedList` of small queues, quite similar to the `ConcurrentQueue` class. Of course this one is not thread-safe.

```
public class SegmentedQueue<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private readonly LinkedList<Queue<T>> _list = new LinkedList<Queue<T>>();
    private const int SEGMENT_SIZE = 32;

    public int Count => _list.Sum(q => q.Count);

    public bool IsEmpty => _list.First == null || _list.First.Value.Count == 0;

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        if (_list.Last == null || _list.Last.Value.Count == SEGMENT_SIZE)
        {
            _list.AddLast(new Queue<T>(SEGMENT_SIZE));
        }
        _list.Last.Value.Enqueue(item);
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        if (this.IsEmpty)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The Queue is empty");
        var item = _list.First.Value.Dequeue();
        if (_list.First.Value.Count == 0)
        {
            _list.RemoveFirst();
        }
        return item;
    }

    public void Clear() => _list.Clear();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => _list.SelectMany(q => q)
        .GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```